# Combine lane detection and object detection in Android, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, opencv, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I want to make application that specified detects with line detection. First I made my application about really basic line detection. Below code is about part of line detection.

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame){
        mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray=inputFrame.gray();
        mat3=inputFrame.rgba();

        // Code about ROI(Region of Interest)
        double m_dWscale = (double)  5/6;
        double m_dHscale = (double) 1/2;
        double m_dWscale1 = (double)  4/6;
        int mRoiWidth = (int)(mRgba.size().width * m_dWscale);
        int mRoiHeight = (int)(mRgba.size().height * m_dHscale);
        int mRoiWidth1 = (int)(mRgba.size().width * m_dWscale1);

        int mRoiX = (int) (mRgba.size().width - mRoiWidth) ;
        int mRoiY = (int) (mRgba.size().height - mRoiHeight) ;

        roi_rect = new Rect(mRoiX,mRoiY,mRoiWidth1,mRoiHeight);
        m_matRoi = mRgba.submat(roi_rect);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(m_matRoi, m_matRoi, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 1);
        m_matRoi.copyTo(mRgba.submat(roi_rect));
       

        //Code about BGR to HSV
        scalarLow=new Scalar(0,0,200);
        scalarHigh=new Scalar(180,255,255);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba.submat(roi_rect),mat1,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        Core.inRange(mat1,scalarLow,scalarHigh,mat2);
        Core.bitwise_and(mRgba.submat(roi_rect),mRgba.submat(roi_rect),mat1,mat2);
        mRgba=mat3;
        Imgproc.dilate(mat1,mat1,new Mat(),new Point(1,2),2);
        Mat edges=new Mat();

        //Code about Canny Edge 
        Imgproc.Canny(mat1,edges,90,150);

        //Code about Hough transform
        Mat lines=new Mat();

        Point p1=new Point();
        Point p2=new Point();
        double a,b;
        double x0,y0;
        Imgproc.HoughLinesP(edges,lines,1.0,Math.PI/180.0,50,100.0,10.0);

        for(int i=0;i<lines.rows();i++) {
            double[] l = lines.get(i, 0);

            Imgproc.line(mRgba.submat(roi_rect), new Point(l[0], l[1]), new Point(l[2], l[3]), new Scalar(0, 0, 255.0), 3);
        }
        //returns output
        return mRgba;
    }
```

And I want to combine upper code with tensorflow lite detection(see the below code please)
Code about tensorflow lite

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame){
        mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray=inputFrame.gray();


        Mat out=new Mat();
        out= objectDetectorClass.recognizeImage(mRgba); //objectDetectorClass is another class which acts about object detection
        return out;
    }
```

So line detection code returns `mRgba` and object detection code returns `out`. I have no idea how to return both lines and object detection.

Thank you!

ps1) I forgot to upload github link about tensorflow lite, object detection application code. https://github.com/bendahouwael/Vehicle-Detection-App-Android. Hope this github helps you.

Comment: Both methods return an object of type `Mat` (or subclass - it's not clear from code what `mRgba` is specifically) - so I think the question is what is the relationship between the two in terms of matrix operations ?  And then which matrix operation is suitable.  Also, in `onCameraFrame` , after `mRgba` is assigned the remaining code seems to have no effect although it's likely I'm misreading it .

Comment: Oh, I solved it. Both returns ```mRgba```.  So output ```mRgba``` and just add ```objectDetectorClass.recognizeImage(mRgba)``` b/c ```objectDetectorClass.recognizeImage``` needs input ```mRgba```.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.
The answer was to return

```
//return mRgba;
        Mat out=new Mat();
        out= objectDetectorClass.recognizeImage(mRgba);
        return out;
```